# What algorithmic solution can match items between two bins containing multiples?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

This is a sorting algorithm question. I break into an outline so it's quicker to read.

---

1. Story. Imagine a family of octuplets--all girls. Every morning mom has to dress these eight girls in shirts and pants (or boots and pants, if you prefer). Mom always buys matching outfits--sometimes several pairs--but not all of the clothes are clean at any given time.
2. Setup. Every morning mom starts with two bins: clean shirts and clean pants.
3. Goal. Automatically pair each shirt with a "style matching" pair of pants (mom doesn't want to think about what matches--[it's a thing](http://www.becomingminimalist.com/wear-one/)).
4. Important. The input set has duplicates (what makes it different than sorting on a *unique key*). We assume shirts and pants are grouped into classes (which identifies a "style"). We name each class: `s1, s2, s3, ..., sn`. And the same for the pants: `p1, p2, p3, ..., pn`. Each `s1` matches with a `p1`. A matching pair can be noted as: `(s1, p1)`.
5. Input.
   The bin of clean shirts can therefore be described as:

   ```
   shirts = [s1,s2,s2,s3,s4,s4,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8]
   ```

   same for pants:

   ```
   pants = [p1,p2,p2,p3,p4,p4,p5,p6,p8,p11,13]
   ```
6. Problem. Does mom have enough clothes for the girls to wear to school? If mom randomly picks any of `[s6,s7]` she won't find matching pants, because the remaining clean pants, `[p11,p13]`, won't match. Drama! Actually, a count is the easy problem.
7. Hard Problem. Mom *always* wants to know if she needs to do laundry. AND, which shirts or pants no longer have a match. So the extension of the algorithm is to *return* a report of both matches *and* mismatches.

   ```
   matches = [(s1,p1), (s2,p2), (s2,p2), (s3,p3), (s4,p4), (s4,p4) (s5,p5) (s6,p6), {s8,p8)]
   mismatches = [(s4,s7), (p11,p13)]
   ```

**My first attempt.** I'm using Python. I thought this would be an easy problem. I would just do a nested `for()` loop:

```
    for s in shirts:
        for p in pants:
            if s matches p:
                give to kid #1
            else:
                continue
```

**Doesn't work.** I can't take a matched pair of pants out of the consideration.

Concretely, `shirts` has the subset `[s4,s4,s4]` and `pants` has the subset `[p4,p4]`. Each time, this nested `for()` loop picks up the next `s4`, it will match only the first `p4`--the algorithm doesn't know there are only two pairs of `p4` pants!

**My next thought,** sort the shirts/pants bins. Split duplicates into a new bins, repeat as with a recursive algorithm.

**Or,** since I'm using Python, should I count the duplicates and make `n` empty lists based on the `max` count of items in `shirts` and `pants`. Having two input sets, it seems to get complicated if set one has 3 multiples and set two has 6 multiples--now I need to decide which input has the most number of duplicates.

**Or.** If there already is an efficient recursive solution, then *force* Python to use something un-Pythonic.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need a multi-set - in python this is `collections.Counter`, if you map the shirts and pants to the outfit they match:

```
>>> shirts = [1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> pants = [1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,8,11,13]
>>> s = Counter(shirts)
>>> p = Counter(pants)
>>> s & p   # matched outfits
Counter({1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 1, 8: 1})
```

This shows all the complete outfits, i.e. 9 complete outfits.
You can also find out which shirts and pants don't match:

```
>>> s - p   # mismatch shirts
Counter({4: 1, 7: 1})
>>> p - s   # mismatch pants
Counter({11: 1, 13: 1})
```

Comment: So that's the easy problem. The hard problem is returning a set of matches and mismatches.

Comment: `s - p` and `p - s` equals the mismatches.

Comment: So brief, I love it! Just on a side note or algorithmic bent, does this problem *sound like anything* to you? Because, I'm not really a mom of octuplets--another benefit of the loops version was I could make *comparison matches*.

Comment: Nothing specific, other multiset operations. What kind of comparison matches are you talking about?